# Symfony: How to load all paths from the same Index route (to use dynamic routing in a React SPA)

Tags: reactjs, symfony, redux

I'm creating a SPA backed by Symfony and ApiPlatform so I want to always load my main route despite the real path of the URL.

I want something like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/*", name="homepage")
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(): Response
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

In my intentions, also if the URL is something like `/path/to/the/spa/page` I want to anyway load the `DefaultController::indexAction()`route.

How to do this? (obviously the provided example doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the solution after an "illumination".

I remembered that there is the possibility to rewrite all URL [adding or removing the trailing slash](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html)

Reading that article I saw this:

```
class RedirectingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{url}", name="remove_trailing_slash",
     *     requirements={"url" = ".*\/$"})
     */
    public function removeTrailingSlash(Request $request)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So, to intercept all URL despite the path, my `DefaultController::indexAction()` becomes this:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{url}",requirements={"url"=".*"}, name="homepage")
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(): Response
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Now all URL are all handled by `DefaultController::indexAction()` despite the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use symfony's event system instead.

Subscribe to either `kernel.request` or `kernel.router` events.

In case of `kernel.request` you have to overtake the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest()`
which priotiry is `32` (use `33` at least).

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class SpaSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 33],
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $html = $this->twig->render('spa.html.twig', [
                'uri' => $request->getUri(),
            ]);

            $response = new Response($html, Response::HTTP_OK);

            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

In case of `kernel.router` use priority `1` at least.

You can use the `php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` command to find out which listeners are registered for events and their priorities.